# how to find string from pool or heap

Tags: java

In below code,

1. if `s3` is commented out, then `s2==s2.intern()` evaluates to `true`. Why?
2. If `s3` is uncommented, then `s2==s2.intern()` evaluates to `false`. Why?

My understanding is that `concat()` method always returns a new string instance, i.e. not one from the string pool.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String s2 = "hitesh".concat("yadav");
    String s3 = "hiteshyadav";

    System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(System.identityHashCode(s2)));
    System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(System.identityHashCode(s2.intern())));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected behavior. Note these facts:

1. when `intern()` actually performs string interning, its return value is identical to its argument;
2. when `intern()` finds an already interned string, it returns that instance instead of the argument.

So, when `s3` is commented out, then the String instance referred to by `s2` is the one being interned and `intern()` returns it. When `s3` is present, then this pre-existing instance is returned by `intern()`.

To verify the above statements and improve your understanding, add the following line to your code:

```
System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(System.identityHashCode(s3)));
```

You'll find out that the second and third line of output are the same.

Comment: if s3 commented this situation s2 refers string from where(heap/pool)?

Comment: All `String` instances reside on the heap, therefore even the instances from the string pool are subject to garbage collection if they become unreachable.